# HIVE NIFI ORC java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column has wrong number of index entries found: 0 expected: 1

Tags: hive, etl, apache-nifi, orc

I have a pipeline in **NIFI** and everything works fine except sometimes(very rarely) some record go to the retry queue in **PUTHIVESTREAMING** processor when trying to write to **HIVE**. 
The nifi logs show the exception

```
    ERROR [put-hive-streaming-0] o.a.h.h.streaming.AbstractRecordWriter Unable to close org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRecordUpdater[hdfs://hdfscluster/user/hive/metastore/bi_sureyield_db.db/bi_sureyield_events/year=2020/month=1/day=10/delta_127318799_127318808/bucket_00000] due to: Column has wrong number of index entries found: 0 expected: 1
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Column has wrong number of index entries found: 0 expected: 1
    at org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl$TreeWriter.writeStripe(WriterImpl.java:695)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl$StructTreeWriter.writeStripe(WriterImpl.java:2147)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl.flushStripe(WriterImpl.java:2661)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl.close(WriterImpl.java:2834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.close(WriterImpl.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRecordUpdater.close(OrcRecordUpdater.java:502)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.AbstractRecordWriter.closeBatch(AbstractRecordWriter.java:218)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl$6.run(HiveEndPoint.java:998)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl$6.run(HiveEndPoint.java:995)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.closeImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:994)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.markDead(HiveEndPoint.java:760)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.commit(HiveEndPoint.java:854)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$4.call(HiveWriter.java:237)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$4.call(HiveWriter.java:234)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.lambda$null$3(HiveWriter.java:373)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.lambda$callWithTimeout$4(HiveWriter.java:373)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2020-04-29 14:55:39,542 ERROR [put-hive-streaming-0] o.a.h.h.streaming.AbstractRecordWriter Unable to close org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRecordUpdater[hdfs://hdfscluster/user/hive/metastore/bi_sureyield_db.db/bi_sureyield_events/year=2020/month=1/day=10/delta_127318799_127318808/bucket_00001] due to: null
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.checkClosed(DFSOutputStream.java:1521)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSOutputSummer.write(FSOutputSummer.java:104)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSDataOutputStream$PositionCache.write(FSDataOutputStream.java:58)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.PhysicalFsWriter$BufferedStream.spillToDiskAndClear(PhysicalFsWriter.java:286)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.PhysicalFsWriter.finalizeStripe(PhysicalFsWriter.java:337)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl.flushStripe(WriterImpl.java:2665)
    at org.apache.orc.impl.WriterImpl.close(WriterImpl.java:2834)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.WriterImpl.close(WriterImpl.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRecordUpdater.close(OrcRecordUpdater.java:502)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.AbstractRecordWriter.closeBatch(AbstractRecordWriter.java:218)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl$6.run(HiveEndPoint.java:998)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl$6.run(HiveEndPoint.java:995)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.closeImpl(HiveEndPoint.java:994)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.markDead(HiveEndPoint.java:760)
    at org.apache.hive.hcatalog.streaming.HiveEndPoint$TransactionBatchImpl.commit(HiveEndPoint.java:854)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$4.call(HiveWriter.java:237)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter$4.call(HiveWriter.java:234)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.lambda$null$3(HiveWriter.java:373)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.nifi.util.hive.HiveWriter.lambda$callWithTimeout$4(HiveWriter.java:373)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm unable to understand where the issue lies and how to fix it.

Comment: After records go to the retry queue, do they stuck there or they get successfully processed?

Comment: they are there. It gives the same error every time

Comment: Probably that files are corrupted. You can right click on the queue and view the queued elements.

Comment: nope! I don't think it is. The data in encrypted and you can only see the data from the queues if its text, this isn't text format. Hence can only see the schema alongside encrypted unicodes.

Comment: Try to route failed files to new block that will decrypt them

Comment: what do you mean by new blocks(which processor)? they are in Avro format not in JSON or text.

Comment: but you can convert them to json using this block: ConvertAvroToJSON